# Office Integration in EPiServer CMS R2

Tags: ms-office, integration, episerver

I am using EPiServer CMS 5 R2 and have a project that I have set up separately from EPiServer 'Site setup' wizard. I now have activated the Office Add-in and cannot connect from Word. When you click the 'Publish to EPiServer CMS' in Word it does not show the site I want to publish to.

I have set up all the correct roles/permissions for the user, and activated all the Office stuff including its permissions in Admin mode.

Can you please help me with activating/enabling the Office publishing to EPiServer site.

I hope this makes sense.

Many thanks,
Edon

Answer (score 1):

see its an old post, but I'll post a link with much useful information around this subject.
A lot of options for what could be wrong.

http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Joe-Bianco/Dates/2009/10/Utilizing-the-Microsoft-Office-Add-In-and-Client-Components-with-EPiServer-CMS/